# Specifiy delimiter in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

How can I specify a `delimiter` in Sublime Text (version 2 or 3)?

I am trying to set some `flags` but I can not see any option to specify a delimiter.

Is my only option that I have left to use `inline flags`?

Comment: what kind of flag you have tried?

Comment: E.g. I would like to use the multi-line flag - it works as an `inline flag` but I can not get it to work using delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Sublime does not have this and I don't know of a package that does - you would be able to apply most commands on a selection of code, but it's not able to open a new buffer.

Comment: Thanks @Amit! I guess all one can do at this point is to use [modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

Comment: Some of those are available via the buttons on the left side of the find panels. I think that's probably why there's no direct way to specify them as flags directly.